# Unable to install hue ue to some JAVA environment issue

Tags: java, maven, hue

I was trying to install hue from github( https://github.com/cloudera/hue)

The first 4 steps were

```
$ git clone http://github.com/cloudera/hue.git
$ cd hue
$ make apps
$ build/env/bin/hue runserver
```

after the first two steps , when i tried the third one it promoted this error

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9:22.923s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 13 21:21:59 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/68M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hue-plugins: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.cloudera.hue:hue-plugins:jar:3.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.7 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

could annyone please guide me in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error relates to Maven not finding the dependencies in your local repo or the Maven central one to be able to build the project. As the project is a Java one it is assuming you have java-7-openjdk installed which it seems you don't.

[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) have a section on how to install it.

You should then be able to run the build.

If it doesn't work after the install find the tools.jar file from the file system and manually install it into Maven using

`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=jdk.tools -DartifactId=jdk.tools -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.7 -Dfile=tools.jar -DgeneratePom=true`

and running the command from within the directory the tools.jar is.